# Check in ajax/jquery a form beform submit ( check the value whether it is in database)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

ajax is not yet sothin i master.
I have two forms field
code :
name :

and the submit button like :

```
<form><input type=text name=code><input type =text name=name/></form>
```

I would like in php/jquery to check if the code the user fill exist in a table of my db.
If it does not exits, when the user leave the textfield to fill the next one, i would like to print a message like: this code is not in the db and then clean the fied. Until the user provide a valide code.

Comment: sorry the form is: <form><input type=text name=code><input type =text name=name/></form>

Comment: native JS, or you have some framework (for ex. jQuery)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your php service returns true or false for validation.
and the placeholder for the error is a label called

then an example (in jQuery) would be

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("form").submit(function(e) {
    var code = $("input[name='code']");
    var error = $("#error");
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = this;
    $.getJSON('urlToPhp',
      { code: code.val() },
      function(valid) {
        if (!valid) {
          error.text(code.val() + ' is not found try another code...');
          code.val('');
        } else {
          form.submit();
        }
      }
    );

  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created a simple example at http://jsfiddle.net/nickywaites/e4rhf/ that will show you have to create a jQuery ajax post request.

I'm not too familiar with php so that part of it I'll have to leave aside although you can use something along the lines of $_POST["Name"].

Here is php example that I googled http://php4every1.com/tutorials/jquery-ajax-tutorial/ that might be better for you.